# html table make javascript run automatically in <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a part of a table as follows:

```
//If (condition is true)
{

 <td width="60" id="myIDValue"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onclick="GetScope(id)" onload="HideSubmit()">1 </td>

}
else
{
 <td width="60" id="myIDValue"  bgcolor="#000000" onclick="GetScope(id)">2 </td>

}
```

My OnClick function works fine but I'm looking to also run my Hidesubmit function if one of the top tds are created ( if the condition is true)

My function:

```
<script>
function HideSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("SubmitButton").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just add `HideSubmit()` in the same block as the one you create the td in?

Comment: This would be great, I'm not very familiar with Javascript but I tried <td>... td properties </td> HideSubmit(); doesn't seem to like that though. Do I have to have something in before the HideSubmit() to make it recognise I want to call the Javascript function?

Comment: How are you generating your tables? Are you using JavaScript/jQuery and then inserting the elements?

Comment: Are you using PHP to generate the td's?

Answer (score 3):

the onload event are only supported by following elements:
body, frame, frameset, iframe, img, link, script

there is other way to resolve your problem.

```
<td width="60" id="myIDValue" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onclick="GetScope(id)" condition="true">1 </td>

window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myIDValue');
    if (el.getAttribute('condition') === 'true') {
        HideSubmit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only supported elements quote clarified my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `$(document).ajaxComplete(hideSubmit);`

Comment: Not really sure where I'm supposed to put that, I tried on the OnLoad event and that didn't work and I tried changing the script function to it instead, unfortunately neither launched the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the ID exists when the document loads and if id exists call the function. You can use javascript to achieve this. Add this to you script tag.

```
    window.onload=function(){
    var myTd = document.getElementById('myIDValue');
    if(myId!=null) {
    HideSubmit();
    }
    };
```